# UpdateAPIView not working: Method "PATCH" not allowed

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I use Django along with **Django REST Framework** to implement a **RESTful API**.

What I have right now:

- A `ContentEntry` model
- A `ContentEntryCreateUpdateSerializer` serializer for my `ContentEntry` model
- A `ContentEntryCreate` view to create some `ContentEntry`*ies*
- A `ContentEntryUpdate` view to **update** the `ContentEntry`*ies*

Here is the code:

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from my_api_app import views


# models.py
class ContentEntry(models.Model):
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container, related_name='content_entries')


# serializers.py
class ContentEntryCreateUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContentEntry
        fields = ('id', 'content', 'quantity', 'container')


# views.py
class ContentEntryCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = ContentEntry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContentEntryCreateUpdateSerializer


# views.py
class ContentEntryUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = ContentEntry.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = ContentEntryCreateUpdateSerializer


# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'content-entry', views.ContentEntryCreate.as_view()),
    url(r'content-entry/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.ContentEntryUpdate.as_view()),
]
```

Everything is working fine except the **`ContentEntryUpdate` which always returns an error**:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 03 May 2017 14:40:03 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.1
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{"detail":"Method \"PATCH\" not allowed."}
```

As you can see in the `Allow` attribute, it seems that only the `POST` and `OPTIONS` methods are allowed by the server.

It's very strange since `generics.UpdateAPIView` defines the `put` and `patch` methods.

I don't think it's a **permission** problem since I allow everything:

```
# settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
    ]
}
```

What should I do **to allow the HTTP `PATCH` and `PUT` methods**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please make sure to mark the URLs with a start and end (^ and $ symbols).

What happens here is without the end mark, `r'content-entry'` matches "/content-entry/4/" and therefore calls the creation view.

Use: `r'^content-entry$'` and `r'^content-entry/(?P<id>\d+)$'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is correct and you are still encountering the issue, please make sure that you are supplying correct record id in the url that is you want to modify.  You can confirm the record with 'GET' request first.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35682148)